# Iptables match special characters / SQL injection detection

Tags: iptables, linux-networking, regex

I want to create an ip6tables rule to detect some well-known SQL injection attempts to web pages.  example: string "*admin' or '1'='1*"

This string should be in HTML body or sent via URI:
Sending this string via URI looks like:
wwww.webpage.comn/unsafe_home.php?username=**admin%27+or+%271%27%3D%271**&Password=blablabl

So special characters are in HEX code according to ASCII table.

But I absolutely can´t write some rule to match exactly this string nor match only " **'** " character at all.

```
ip6tables - I forward 1 -p tcp --dport 80 -m state --state ESTABLISHED -m string --hex-string "|27|" --algo bm -j LOG --log-prefix "HEX-TEST"
```

I had a successful match only when I tested the string of admin alone.

```
ip6tables - I forward 1 -p tcp --dport 80 -m state --state ESTABLISHED -m string --string "admin" --algo bm -j LOG --log-prefix "ADMIN_TEST"
```

Any idea how to write some regular expression to match whole this string with special characters? 
Thank you in advance.

Comment: I don't see anywhere that you tried to actually match on the string? `admin%27+or+%271%27%3D%271`